# How to return Custom object with Criteria query

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api, criteriaquery

I need to return a custom object with criteria query. With normal fields it is working fine.
When i used List, it is throwing exception.

```
 @Entity
 class A {
      ...... remaining fields
      @OnetoMany()
      @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
      List<B> b;
      @Column
      double amount;
  }

 @Entity
 class B {
     ...... remaining fields
     @Column
     String name;
 }
class customObject {
    List<B> b;
    double amount;
}
```

When I tried this one am getting exception below 
**Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class
Expected arguments are: java.util.Collection,string.** 
Can some please tell me how to do this. Thank you.